# does mono/.Net GC release free allocated memory back to OS after collection? if not, why?

Tags: c#, memory, garbage-collection

I heard many times that once C# managed program request more memory from OS, it doesn't free it back, unless system is out of memory. Eg. when object is collected, it gets deleted, and memory that was occupied by the object is free to reuse by another managed object, but memory itself is not returned to operating system (for example, mono on unix wouldn't call `brk` / `sbrk` to decrease the amount of virtual memory available to the process back to what it was before its allocation).

I don't know if this really happens or not, but I can see that my c# applications, running on linux, use small amount of memory on beginning, then when I do something memory expensive, it allocates more of it, but later on when all objects get deleted (I can verify that by putting debug message to destructors), the memory is not free'd. On other hand no more memory is allocated when I run that memory expensive operation again. The program just keep on eating the same amount of memory until it is terminated.

Maybe it is just my misunderstanding of how GC in .net works, but if it really does work like this, why is that? What is a benefit of keeping the allocated memory for later, instead of returning it back to the system? How can it even know if system need it back or not? What about other application that would crash or couldn't start because of OOM caused by this effect?

I know that people will probably answer something like "GC manages memory better than you ever could, just don't care about it" or "GC knows what it does best" or "it doesn't matter at all, it's just virtual memory" but it does matter, on my 2gb laptop I am running OOM (and kernel OOM killer gets started because of that) very often when I am running any C# applications after some time precisely because of this irresponsible memory management.

Note: I was testing this all on mono in linux because I really have hard times understanding how windows manage memory, so debugging on linux is much easier for me, also linux memory management is open source code, memory management of windows kernel / .Net is rather mystery for me

Comment: Not an answer but I recommend to search for articles/videos from [Maoni Stephens](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Maoni-Stephens-CLR-45-Server-Background-GC). She is the GC Lead developer...

Comment: This is a very specific Linux issue, you got what you asked for.  Just [turn it off](http://jurjenbokma.com/ApprenticesNotes/turing_off_overcommit.html).

Answer (score 4):

The memory manager works this way because there is no benefit of having a lot of unused system memory when you don't need it.

If the memory manager would always try to have as little memory allocated as possible, that would mean that it would do a lot of work for no reason. It would only slow the application down, and the only benefit would be more free memory that no application is using.

Whenever the system needs more memory, it will tell the running applications to return as much as possible. The same signal is also sent to an application when you minimise it.

If this doesn't work the same with Mono in Linux, then that is a problem with that specific implementation.

Comment: The first line seems contradictory to the rest...?

Comment: @MarcGravell: In what way?

Comment: Ah, I think I see : I was reading the first line as "in your process" - i.e. relating to the memory manager. If you mean "in your overall system", then: great

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yes, exactly. I think it's clearer now.

Comment: how does the system tell the processes to give it back some memory? what signal is that? and how it decide that it needs more memory? if some process is started and ask for 200mb of ram, it can hardly suspend it until 200mb is freed by other processes.

Comment: I mean, in theory this all sounds cool, but in practice it's more like a science fiction... You can't just have OS kernel ask processes to give it back some memory. There is no such a thing at least in UNIX world and I doubt there is in windows kernel. You can only deny `brk` or `sbrk` call (on UNIX). Kernel isn't supposed to forcefully "take away" the memory from processes, it can only kill them in case it really needs more ram, but that should happen very rarely. I just can't imagine how this "I am now out of memory, please processes, give me some back" works in real.

Comment: @Petr: It's not science fiction, that's exactly how it works. The system uses the `SetProcessWorkingSetSize` method to signal to the memory manager to free up memory. If Unix is lacking such means of communicating, that is of course a problem. Regarding the allocation process, if a process asks for memory, it's naturally suspended while the system is trying to allocate the memory. That is normal for any call, the execution resumes when the call returns.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, if an app needs memory once, it will need it again. Releasing memory back to the OS only to request it back again is overhead, and if nothing else wants the memory: *why bother?*. It is trying to optimize for the very likely scenario of wanting it again. Additionally, releasing it back requires entire / contiguous blocks that can be handed back, which has very specific impact on things like compaction: it isn't quite as simple as "hey, I'm not using most of this : have it back" - it needs to figure out what blocks *can* be released, presumably after a full collect and compact (relocate objects etc) cycle.

Comment: are you sure that once app needs memory, it will need it again? what if I open 30 tabs in a browser, then decide to close 20 of them just to free some memory so that I can launch some other program that would need it. If memory wasn't returned back to system, I would have to terminate whole application everytime (which I actually have to do now)

Comment: @Petr that depends on how the browser is implemented; in the case of chrome: process per tab